# SMPS mains hum on guitar rig

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, noise, mains

My guitar rig consists of

Guitar -> Audio Interface (Steinberg UR22) -> Laptop (via USB).

I listen to the (processed) audio using headphones connected to the audio interface.

**ISSUE:**

When the power supply of my laptop is connected to an **unearthed** outlet, I pick up a loud 50Hz hum, which almost disappears when I touch any metal part of the rig.

The noise also disappears if the power supply is connected to an earthed outlet or disconnected altogether (so the laptop runs on battery power).

**Disclaimer:** I understand that very similar (if not identical) issues have been discussed in many places, including here, but after a week of hunting for info I am still quite confused.

**CONJECTURES:**

After some reading and experimentation, I concluded that this hum is **mains hum** coming from the SMPS secondary being capacitively coupled to the primary. Indeed I can measure a 50Hz AC voltage (~53 volts) between the "-" pin of the power supply (or other conducting surfaces of the rig) and earth.

This AC voltage is in turn sent to the guitar via the audio cable, where it interacts with the pickups and results in the hum (I am saying this because the noise completely disappears if I turn the volume to zero *using the guitar potenziometer*, but I am not sure what is going on exactly).

I would like to solve the issue *without having to use an earthed outlet*, as they are only available in the kitchen and bathroom in my apartment (furthermore, no exposed pipes are available outside of these two rooms). I believe this to be safe since I am using a class II power supply. However, my understanding of electronics is very limited, so I would like to ask your opinion before I waste any money in trial and error.

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTIONS?**

1. The audio interface can be powered by an external 5V power supply. The noise is quite a bit lower with a phone charger supply, but it does not disappear entirely so it would not be a "complete" solution in any case. Unfortunately, when the laptop is connected to its own power supply, its floating ground is transmitted to the audio interface via USB even when the latter is powered externally. I am thinking that a USB isolator would do the trick, but such devices (especially those supporting 480Mbps) seem to be quite expensive.
2. I am also wondering whether an isolation transformer between the guitar and the audio interface, such as the Behringer HD400, could possibly help. I do not see how it can block the AC noise from reaching the guitar though.
3. Are there other ways to isolate the ground of the guitar pickups from the floating ground of the audio interface?

**BONUS QUESTION:**

Out of curiosity, I would like to understand why touching metal parts of the rig (such as the guitar strings or the audio interface itself) eliminates the noise, *even when my body is not connected to earth*. Would it be possible to build a circuit that mimics this effect?

In any case, any thoughts on the matter would be greatly appreciated.